# TypeORM: Updating data (with relations) via Repository API

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I have two entities (tables): **users** and **roles**. There is a many-to-one relation between both entities (a user can have one role, roles can be related to many users). Now I want to update the user entity (which can also include an update of the user's role) by excuting following commands:

```
const user = await this.userRepository.preload(partialUser);
await this.userRepository.save(user);
return user;
```

## Expected behavior

1. `partialUser` (user properties to update) is merged with user data from database including `role`
2. `user` (merged object) is saved to database
3. new user object is returned to caller (including role)

## What happens

1. user is merged, but `role` is not loaded (but if I add a child property `role` to `partialUser`, it's okay)
2. `user` (merged object) is saved to database (also with `role`, if it was part of `partialUser`)
3. new user object is returned, but it's missing role, if role was not updated via partialUser

## Question

Why is `role` not loaded via `preload` nor `return` after `save`? Are TypeORM repositories not well made for relations or do I use it incorrectly?

## My workaround

At the moment I have to read the whole `user` entity again after saving it, so that the full object (including `role` relation) can be returned to the caller. I think thats not very efficient. Is it intended that way?

```
const user = await this.userRepository.preload(partialUser);
await this.userRepository.save(user);

return this.userRepository.findOne({
  where: { id: user.id },
  relations: ['role']
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeORM has support for such use-cases. It's done using the eager-loading flag i.e. `eager: true` that you can set to the relation. Now everytime you fetch this record, the relation will be fetched by default and returned in the response. Example code that you can use in User model:

```
@ManyToMany(type => Role, role => role.User, {
  eager: true
})
public roles: Role[];
```

Comment: You could also resort to use relations in your query. Example adapted from their docs:
`const users= await userRepository.find({ relations: ["roles"] });`

Comment: It doesn't work for 'preload'. It works for 'find'